# Groovy date format for UTC with milliseconds

Tags: date, datetime, groovy

I'm having trouble finding a good way of formatting a UTC-time stamp with this format: `yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.<three additional digits>`

I wasn't able to find any character that represents milliseconds/hundredths, I'm not even sure this is possible, to parse that format that is.

Ideally I'd like to use the `parseToStringDate` that's part of the Date library.

My plan b is to convert `yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss` to milliseconds and then add the three last digits to that number.

Comment: I know the OP specified format, but others might be interested in epoch `System.currentTimeMillis())` also.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Use `yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS`

This will get you milliseconds as well.

Test Code:

```
def now = new Date()
println now.format("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))
```

Comment: I tried .SSS it didn't work. I set the timezone now and it is a bit better, thing is I have a string coming in and parseToStringDate gives me an exception. Any ideas on how I can import my current date and get a Date from it?

Comment: Hi again! So basically now.parse("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS","20140104-11:00:01:001") gives me exactly what I want but that method is deprecated!

Comment: @marko Use static parse method as `Date.parse("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS","20140104-11:00:01.001")` and remember milliseconds is formatted by `.` instead of `:`.

Comment: Note that `TimeZone.setDefault(....)` may affect other parts of your application where you may or may not want UTC as the default! The following is localised if that's what you want: `now.format("yyyyMMdd-HH:mm:ss.SSS", TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC'))`

Comment: The format seems to be '"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'' for wss4j

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')
Date date = new Date()
String newdate = date.format("YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.Ms")
log.info newdate
```

Comment: You never use the `TimeZone.getTimeZone('UTC')` result, so this line actually doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

I would convert it like that:

```
def now = new Date()
println now.format("YYYYMMdd-HH:mm:ss")
```

Comment: there is no ms here.