# How to specifically format date/time in Groovy

Tags: date, groovy

I need to be able to timestamp things in this format:

```
2018-01-26T10:47:44.686000-08:00
```

I am not sure how exactly to do this - and having trouble following the docs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Groovy date format for UTC with milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923364/groovy-date-format-for-utc-with-milliseconds)

Answer (score 1):

Or just the groovy [`format`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#format(java.lang.String)) extension to the java.util.Date class:

```
def date = new Date()
println(date.format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to take a look at the SimpleDateFormat API: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

For example, a formatter like you mentioned above would be:

```
def df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSSSSZ")
println df.format(new Date())
```