# Groovy: Time in ISO 8601 format

Tags: datetime, groovy, jenkins-groovy

How to get the current time and 15 min ago time in iso 8601 format (YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss) in groovy?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Groovy date format for UTC with milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20923364/groovy-date-format-for-utc-with-milliseconds)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can formast the date in any way you want in Groovy, by doing e.g.

```
println new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd HH.mm.ss.SSSSS Z")
```

Then, you can do calculations on the date, like this:

```
new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-91*60*1000)
```

which will minus 91 minutes (91min * 60sec * 1000ms).

Then you can put the statements together, which is why Groovy is great:

```
def a = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-91*60*1000).format("YYYY-MM-DD")
```

And so you can get the half before the T. And the half after the T:

```
def b = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()-91*60*1000).format("HH:mm:ss")
```

And then concatenate them with a T:

```
println "91 minutes ago in iso 8601 format is: ${a}T${b}"
```

There are other ways of doing it, like with `TimeCategory.minus`, but this is a good illustration. I used 91 minutes, but you can adapt it to your own requirtement.

Answer (score 4):

You can use java time's `Instant` and the `toString()` format

```
import java.time.*

def now = Instant.now()

def fifteenAgo = now.minus(Duration.ofMinutes(15))

println "Now is ${now} and 15 mins ago was ${fifteenAgo}"
```

Prints:

```
Now is 2020-06-30T19:53:17.445039Z and 15 mins ago was 2020-06-30T19:38:17.445039Z
```